# Using an input file: output the median (Java)

Tags: java

I have been working on this for a while here is my code so far. I've been quite lost for sometime, because I do not know how to either change the number of items in an array `int m[] = new int[variable]` or remove the zeros/shift the array. The zeros are the problem, because I need to sort the array and find the median.

Here's the assignment:

> #### Task Description
>
> Median plays an important role in the world of statistics. By definition, it is a value which divides an array into two equal parts. In this problem you are to determine the current median of some long integers.
>
> Suppose, we have five numbers {1,3,6,2,7}. In this case, 3 is the median as it has exactly two numbers on its each side. {1,2} and {6,7}.
>
> If there are even number of values like {1,3,6,2,7,8}, only one value cannot split this array into equal two parts, so we consider the average of the middle values {3,6}. Thus, the median will be (3+6)/2 = 4.5. In this problem, you have to print only the integer part, not the fractional. As a result, according to this problem, the median will be 4!
>
> #### Program Input
>
> The input file (c:\codewars\prob06.in) contains a number of integers X ( 0 <= X < 2^31 ) and total number of integers N is less than 10000. The input file will contain a ‘0” to signify the end of the list of integers. When you read in a ‘0’, your program must exit without calculating a new median with the number 0.
>
> ```
> 1 3 4 60 70 50 2 0
> ```
>
> #### Program Output
>
> As each number is read in, recalculate the median and display it to the screen.
>
> ```
> 1 2 3 3 4 27 4
> ```

Here's my attempt so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Median {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        
        String fileName = "textfile.txt";
        
        //Labels scanner
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        int fileLen=0;
        int[] m = new int[1000];


        try{
            inputStream = new Scanner (new File (fileName));
            LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
            lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            fileLen = lnr.getLineNumber();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not open the file named: " + fileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        
        int middle = 0;

        for (int counter=0;counter<fileLen && inputStream.hasNextInt();counter++){
            
            int unChecked = inputStream.nextInt();
            if (unChecked != 0) {
                m[counter]=unChecked;
                removeZeros(m);
                median(m, fileLen);
                //Arrays.sort(m);
            }else if (unChecked == 0){
                counter+=fileLen;
            }
        }
        }
    
        
            
        
        
    
    
    
    
    public static int median(int m[],int fileLen) {
        int[] b = new int[fileLen];
        System.arraycopy(m, 0, b, 0, b.length);
        Arrays.sort(b);
        System.out.println(b[1]);
        if (m.length % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println((b[(b.length / 2) - 1] + b[b.length / 2]) / 2);
        return (b[(b.length / 2) - 1] + b[b.length / 2]) / 2;
        } else {
        System.out.println(b[b.length / 2]);
        return b[b.length / 2];
        }
    }
    
    static void removeZeros(int m[]) {
        
        int counter2=0,counter4=0;
        for(int counter=0;counter<m.length;counter++){
            if (m[counter]!=0){
                counter2++;
                System.out.println(m[counter]);
            }
        }
        
        int d[] = new int [counter2];
        for(int counter=0;counter<m.length;counter++){
            if (m[counter]==0){
                d[counter4] = m[counter];
                counter4++;
            }
        }
            
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove zeros? There's no way to change the size of an array in Java by the way, what you need to do is create a new array and copy the elements you want to keep.

Comment: Hint: look into ArrayList: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Yes, after reading the entire assignment I'd say `ArrayList` is your best bet.

Comment: Can you show me some examples? I don't understand that link.

Comment: @KhalobC You can just google. However if you find that hard here are some links. [Link1](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=234) and [Link2](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/array_list_demo.shtml)

Comment: Why are you removing 0s? If there is a 0 in your array, that means you're at the end of the list, and should not be getting any more input... And in your `removeZeros` function, all you are doing is adding 0s to a local array. That isn't going to take them out of the the original array, and might cause an IndexOutOfRange exception if for some reason there are more 0s than non-zero numbers in `m`.

Answer (score 0):

`getLineNumber` will probably always return 1 in your program (or some value != the current position). This will cause incorrect behaviour for `median` and cause your program to terminate early. So get rid of `lnr` and `fileLen` and pass `counter+1` to the median function instead.

Some tips:

- Just put `break;` after `if (unChecked == 0)`.
- For `if (unChecked != 0) ... else if (unChecked == 0)`, you can remove the `if (unChecked == 0)`.
- Get rid of `removeZeros`, the functionality doesn't fit the requirements of the problem.
- Sorting the whole set on every input number is a bad idea, look into [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) to sort it as you go.